# grabbing json contents every 5 seconds using titanium

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile

I want to do the following:

every 5 seconds, access a url, grab the json contents from the url, and display on the iphone app screen.

how can I do this using titanium mobile?

I tried using the onload and addEventListener function, but to no avail...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My code here is just to show you how to get the data, but not exactly every 5 seconds. It execute the grabbing json 5 seconds after each request loaded.

```
function grab_json() {
    // do something with grabbing json data
    var xhr = Titanium.Network.createHTTPClient({
        onload: function(e) {
            // do something

            // when finish, grab the json data in the next 5 seconds
            setTimeout(function() {
                grab_json();
            }, 5000);
        }
    });
    xhr.open("GET", "your-url-here");
    xhr.send();
}

// execute the function when view loaded
grab_json();
```